# Can connecting multiple devices to a USB hub damage them?

Tags: windows-10, usb, power, usb-hub, sim

I have a laptop with only three USB ports. Every time I have to connect my Thrustmaster Ferrari Red Legend Edition Racing wheel to my PC, it takes up the only free port on my laptop as my mouse and keyboard are connected to the other two.

Since my headphones are also USB, to use both of them together I used an old USB hub I had lying around. This hub takes one port and extends it to four. I connected my wheel and headphones to the hub but got an error stating that a device wasn't recognised.

I immediately disconnected everything and tried connecting the wheel directly to my laptop. The wheel worked fine but my pedals won't work anymore. Everything was working fine before this. I've tried everything from rebooting my PC to reinstalling the drivers and even plugging the wheel into another PC. The pedals just don't work.

The pedal set connects to the main wheel via an RJ11 cable and the wheel then connects by USB. My guess is, somehow I've fried the potentiometers on the pedal set.

My headphones work fine though. And the USB port on my laptop is okay as well.

My question is, can using a USB hub burn your peripherals? If yes then, in this case, what could be the damage to the pedal set? Is my theory correct?

Comment: I never heard of this happening but I guess there is a first for everything. You check the pedal pots with an ohmmeter.

Comment: Sounds like coincidence to me. Very little chance the hub did this. You probably have a problem with the cable or the pedals that is unrelated.

Comment: @Appleoddity I've gone through all the connections. The cable is fine and was never subjected to even mild tension anyway... My only guess is the pedal pots failing